# cmd can't connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

My Windows 7 PC connects to the internet fine, apart from cmd.exe.

None of the commands like `ping` or `ftp` work.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

---

```
C:\...\> ftp
ftp> open 123.123.123.123
ftp>
```

Nothing happens. I type `open` and the server's address, and it just doesn't do anything. No feedback either.

My macbook pro (which is not on the same local network, if that's important) and other computers, as well as online ftp clients, can connect fine.

I also try `ftp 123.123.123.123` direct and that also doesn't work. Same thing, no feedback.

```
C:\...\> ping 123.123.123.123

Envoi d'une requête 'Ping' 123.123.123.123 avec 32 octets de données :
Défaillance générale.
Défaillance générale.
Défaillance générale.
```

It is french, it means "general failure." Same error for any server.

My computer connects to the internet fine though through every other program.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the commands you are using and the error messages you are seeing. Without this information your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill done

Comment: "connect to internet" is very different from trying ping and ftp with a specific address. Many servers won't react to ping requests. Same for ftp. Can you ftp to the same address in a browser? Also, your local network could cause this -- and where is the server located, because some low-cost routers have problems if the server has the same internet uplink as the client, if it is addressed by its public IP address. -- And what exactly is "every other program"?

Comment: @ClassStacker I said already I tried with lots of servers. And yes, I said already that I can ping/ftp that server from other computers. I appreciate my question may not be as informative as possible though, but that's because I don't yet have all the info.

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm sorry but I can't find any hint that you already said that. As I wrote, "connect to Internet" can mean anything. And your thesis is that it's related to the command line. So my question was whether you can ftp to the server from a browser or other GUI ftp client. But you decided to ignore that.

Comment: @ClassStacker yes, can access from browser via `ftp://123.123.123.123`

Comment: If we ignore the `ping` aspect which I see as unclarified, take into account that the Windows command line `ftp` client does not support the FTP passive mode and that the network infrastructure (firewall, routers) may prevent FTP active mode. Could this be the problem? You never said which other commands on the command line, besides for `ping` and `ftp`, you tried.

Answer (score 1):

#### None of the commands like ping or ftp work.

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Are these meant to be run one before the next and test in between if its working yet? Or should I just run them all and then test again?

Comment: You might as well run them all and then test.